# Angularjs testing: using $broadcast doesn't fill variables as expected

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, karma-jasmine

In my scenerio I do the following:

1) Grab data from socket
2) Raise an event $scope.$broadcast('socket:newData', data)
3) Watch it in the directive:

```
$scope.processedData = [];
$scope.$on('socket:newData', function(e,data){
  // gets data processed, and adds it to $scope.processedData
  myService.dataProcess($scope.processedData, data);
});
```

In the app it works fine and I get the data. In my test I define $rootScope and $compile. The directive builds nicely and I do some tests for its isolated scope as well as HTML and everything seems to be in order (including templates and subdirectives loading).

**The problem is: *$scope.prcessedData* remains empty.**

Here is my test code:

```
beforeEach(module('app'));

beforeEach(_inject(function(_$rootScope_, _$compile_, _myService_){
  $rootScope = _$rootScope_;
  $compile - _$compile_;
  myService = _myService_;
  element = angular.element('<my-directive></my-directive>');
  $compile(element)($rootScope);
}));

beforeEach(function(){
  spyOn(myService, 'dataProcess');
  var data = getMockData(); // returns some data sample that's in the format of the data recieved from the socket
  $rootScope.$broadcast('socket:newData', data);
  $rootScope.$apply();
    });

it('Processed data should be filled', function(){
  // *getExpected* returns the expected processed data  
  expect(element.isolateScope().processedData).toEqual(getExpected(getMockData()));
});
```

But *element.isolateScope().processedData* returns []...

I've tried the following to make sure the processing function runs its course:

```
it('Expect the function "dataProcess" to run', function(){
  expect(myService.dataProcess).toHaveBeenCalledWith(element.isolateScope().processedData, getMockData());
});
```

Which passes and still *element.isolateScope().processedData* returns `[]`...

How can I retrieve the values after the function has run its course?

Answer (score 0):

I would update the first beforeEach method as follows:

```
beforeEach(_inject(function(_$rootScope_, _$compile_, _myService_){
    $rootScope = _$rootScope_;
    $compile - _$compile_;
    myService = _myService_;
    element = $compile(html)(scope);
    scope.$digest();
    isolateScope = element.isolateScope();
}));
```

I had similar but different issues which were solved by calling $digest() after $compile.

Comment: I've tried it before, but it doesn't work. I've also tried using the "done" method, but still the same... []